# Divide by 10 using bit shifts?

Tags: math, bit, micro-optimization, low-level, integer-division

Is it possible to divide an unsigned integer by 10 by using pure bit shifts, addition, subtraction and *maybe* multiply?  Using a processor with very limited resources and slow divide.

Comment: It's possible (repeated subtraction is division), but the question is whether it's any faster than the slow division.

Comment: @esnyder. Sorry, I can't understand you. Are you talking in base 17 or base 22?

Comment: Base large two.  Shifting right divides by 2^n which would solve your question if by "10" you mean 16 decimal or 10h.

Comment: Are you arguing with me?  I'm actually trying to admit that *I* failed to mention my answer was not for decimal.... Might be a bit obscure, but that was my intention.

Comment: @Thomas O - see my comment.  I don't notice an upvote....

Comment: @esynder, Yes, I guess I was arguing with you, over the interpretation of 10(base 10) as 10(base 16). I think such an interpretation by default is unusual, at best.

Comment: Related: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi): If you have a fast multiply, you can divide by compile-time constants with just a multiply and a shift of the high half, getting the correct result for every dividend (unlike the current accepted answer).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Editor's note: this is *not* actually what compilers do, and gives the wrong answer for large positive integers ending with 9, starting with `div10(1073741829) = 107374183` not `107374182` ([Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:25,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:25),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits.h%3E%0A%0Aint32_t+div10(int32_t+dividend)%0A%7B%0A++++int64_t+invDivisor+%3D+0x1999999A%3B%0A++++return+(int32_t)+((invDivisor+*+dividend)+%3E%3E+32)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09//+64-bit+counter+so+we+can+loop+the+entire+range+of+int%0A//%09for(int64_t+i+%3D+INT_MIN+%3B+i+%3C%3D+INT_MAX+%3B+i%2B%2B+)+%7B+++++//+all+integers%0A//%09for(int64_t+i+%3D+0+%3B+i+%3E%3D+INT_MIN+%3B+i--+)+%7B++++++++++++++//+negative+integers%0A%09for(int64_t+i+%3D+0+%3B+i+%3C%3D+INT_MAX+%3B+i%2B%2B+)+%7B+++++++++++//+positive+integers,+correct+for+many+small+integers%0A%09%09int32_t+d10+%3D+div10(i)%3B%0A%09%09int32_t+correct+%3D+(int32_t)i/10%3B++++//+signed+division%0A%09%09if+(d10+!!%3D+correct)+%7B%0A%09%09%09printf(%22mismatch:+div10(%25ld)+%3D+%25d.++Correct+%3D+%25d%5Cn%22,+i,+d10,+correct)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.949699289229095,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.67060294695994,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+5.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.05030071077092,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).  It is exact for inputs smaller than `0x40000005`, though, which may be sufficient for some uses.

Compilers (including MSVC) do use fixed-point multiplicative inverses for constant divisors, but they use a different magic constant and shift on the high-half result to get an exact result for all possible inputs, matching what the C abstract machine requires.  See [Granlund & Montgomery's paper](https://gmplib.org/%7Etege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf) on the algorithm.

See [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi) for examples of the actual x86 asm gcc, clang, MSVC, ICC, and other modern compilers make.

---

#### This is a fast approximation that's inexact for large inputs

It's even faster than the exact division via multiply + right-shift that compilers use.

You can use the high half of a multiply result for divisions by small integral constants. Assume a 32-bit machine (code can be adjusted accordingly):

```
int32_t div10(int32_t dividend)
{
    int64_t invDivisor = 0x1999999A;
    return (int32_t) ((invDivisor * dividend) >> 32);
}
```

What's going here is that we're multiplying by a close approximation of 1/10 * 2^32 and then removing the 2^32. This approach can be adapted to different divisors and different bit widths.

This works great for the ia32 architecture, since its IMUL instruction will put the 64-bit product into edx:eax, and the edx value will be the wanted value. Viz (assuming dividend is passed in ecx (fastcall) and quotient returned in eax)

```
div10 proc 
    mov    eax,1999999Ah    ; 1/10 * 2^32
    imul   ecx              ; edx:eax = dividend / 10 * 2 ^32
    mov    eax,edx          ; eax = dividend / 10
    ret
endp
```

Even on a machine with a slow multiply instruction, this will be faster than a software or even hardware divide.

Comment: +1, and I'd like to emphasise that the compiler will do this for you automatically when you write "x/10"

Comment: hmm, isn't there some numerical inaccuracy here?

Comment: You're always going to have numerical inaccuracy when doing integer divides: What do you you get when you divide 28 by 10 using integers? Answer: 2.

Comment: There is no numerical inaccuracy in integer division, the result is exactly specified.  However, the formula above is only exact for certain divisors. 
Even 10 is inaccurate if you want to do unsigned arithmetic: `4294967219 / 10 = 429496721`, but `4294967219 * div >> 32 = 429496722`  For larger divisors, the signed version will be inaccurate as well.

Comment: @Theran: No, compilers including MSVC will compile `x/10` to [a fixed-point multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)  (and make extra code to handle negative inputs for signed division) to give the correct answer for all possible 32-bit inputs.  For unsigned division by 10, MSVC (and other compilers) (https://godbolt.org/g/aAq7jx) will multiply by `0xcccccccd` and right-shift the high half by 3.

Comment: I wrote [a test program for this](https://godbolt.org/g/Kd9Q4A), comparing the results against `i/10`.  It's wrong for large positive integers ending with 9, starting with `div10(1073741829) = 107374183.  Correct = 107374182`.  It's also wrong for most (all?) negative integers, e.g. `div10(-1) = -1.  Correct = 0`.  @JasonS is correct that this doesn't implement the C semantics of `x / 10`.

Comment: @PeterCordes there's a neat video by Matt Godbolt that touches upon what the compiler does for division; sometimes it uses multiplication. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4

Answer (score 48):

Though the answers given so far match the actual question, they do not match the title. So here's a solution heavily inspired by [Hacker's Delight](http://web.archive.org/web/20180517023231/http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) that really uses only bit shifts.

```c++
unsigned divu10(unsigned n) {
    unsigned q, r;
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - (((q << 2) + q) << 1);
    return q + (r > 9);
}
```

I think that this is the best solution for architectures that lack a multiply instruction.

Comment: pdf not available anymore

Comment: how can we adapt it for 10^N?

Comment: The original site is dead, the link points now to the archived version in the Wayback Machine. In the linked PDF you will find code for division by 100 and 1000. Please be aware that these still contain a multiply operation which would need to replaced with shifts and adds. Also, the divu100 and divu1000 code contains many shifts which are not a multiple of 8, so if you are on an architecture which has neither a barrel shifter nor a muliply instruction, you might be better off by applying divu10 repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you! It's for FPGA/RTL, I will adapt depending on the timing I can get. I just found the link to this pdf literally everywhere such a question is asked. Without being able to find the actual file. Thanks again!

Comment: Often architectures that lack MUL also lack support for bit shifting more than one bit at a time, like AVR 8 bit, where this results in a mountain of loops for the various bit shifts

Comment: You could save an op with `q = n - (n >> 2);`

Answer (score 22):

Of course you can if you can live with some loss in precision. If you know the value range of your input values you can come up with a bit shift and a multiplication which is exact.
Some examples how you can divide by 10, 60, ... like it is described in this blog to format [time the fastest way](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/04/23/76146.aspx) possible.

```
temp = (ms * 205) >> 11;  // 205/2048 is nearly the same as /10
```

Comment: You have to be aware that the intermediate value `(ms * 205)` can overflow.

Comment: If you do  int ms = 205 * (i >> 11); you will get wrong values if the numbers are small. You need a test suite to ensure that in a given value range the results are correct.

Comment: this is accurate for ms = 0..1028

Comment: Why 205 specifically?

Comment: @ernesto >> 11 is a division of 2048. When you want to divide by ten you need to divide that by 2048/10 which is 204,8 or 205 as closest integer number.

Comment: I just love the simplicity, this is really great idea

Comment: It is exactly the same for 0 <= ms < 1029.

Comment: And for 0 <= ms < 179, you can even do this with 10 instead of 11 shifts:

`temp = (ms * 103) >> 10;`

Answer (score 10):

to expand Alois's answer a bit, we can expand the suggested `y = (x * 205) >> 11` for a few more multiples/shifts:

```
y = (ms *        1) >>  3 // first error 8
y = (ms *        2) >>  4 // 8
y = (ms *        4) >>  5 // 8
y = (ms *        7) >>  6 // 19
y = (ms *       13) >>  7 // 69
y = (ms *       26) >>  8 // 69
y = (ms *       52) >>  9 // 69
y = (ms *      103) >> 10 // 179
y = (ms *      205) >> 11 // 1029
y = (ms *      410) >> 12 // 1029
y = (ms *      820) >> 13 // 1029
y = (ms *     1639) >> 14 // 2739
y = (ms *     3277) >> 15 // 16389
y = (ms *     6554) >> 16 // 16389
y = (ms *    13108) >> 17 // 16389
y = (ms *    26215) >> 18 // 43699
y = (ms *    52429) >> 19 // 262149
y = (ms *   104858) >> 20 // 262149
y = (ms *   209716) >> 21 // 262149
y = (ms *   419431) >> 22 // 699059
y = (ms *   838861) >> 23 // 4194309
y = (ms *  1677722) >> 24 // 4194309
y = (ms *  3355444) >> 25 // 4194309
y = (ms *  6710887) >> 26 // 11184819
y = (ms * 13421773) >> 27 // 67108869
```

each line is a single, independent, calculation, and you'll see your first "error"/incorrect result at the value shown in the comment.  you're generally better off taking the smallest shift for a given error value as this will minimise the extra bits needed to store the intermediate value in the calculation, e.g. `(x * 13) >> 7` is "better" than `(x * 52) >> 9` as it needs two less bits of overhead, while both start to give wrong answers above 68.

if you want to calculate more of these, the following (Python) code can be used:

```
def mul_from_shift(shift):
    mid = 2**shift + 5.
    return int(round(mid / 10.))
```

and I did the obvious thing for calculating when this approximation starts to go wrong with:

```
def first_err(mul, shift):
    i = 1
    while True:
        y = (i * mul) >> shift
        if y != i // 10:
            return i
        i += 1
```

(note that `//` is used for "integer" division, i.e. it truncates/rounds towards zero)

the reason for the "3/1" pattern in errors (i.e. 8 repeats 3 times followed by 9) seems to be due to the change in bases, i.e. `log2(10)` is ~3.32.  if we plot the errors we get the following:

[image: errors]

where the relative error is given by: `mul_from_shift(shift) / (1<<shift) - 0.1`

Comment: What is `ms` in your test?

Comment: @Alexis I borrowed that name from Alois's answer, it's just the value you want to divide.  maybe it's short for "multiply shift"?

Comment: I understand but what is the value in comment at each line then?

Comment: @Alexis not sure if I can explain any better than the paragraph under the block...  it's the first value of `ms` that will give an incorrect answer, i.e. the parameters work for any value < the comment

Comment: oups sorry I didn't get it at the first read. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Considering [Kuba Ober’s response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275429/3789665), there is another one in the same vein.
It uses iterative approximation of the result, but I wouldn’t expect any surprising performances.

Let say we have to find `x` where `x = v / 10`.

We’ll use the inverse operation `v = x * 10` because it has the nice property that when `x = a + b`, then `x * 10 = a * 10 + b * 10`.

Let use `x` as variable holding the best approximation of result so far. When the search ends, `x` Will hold the result. We’ll set each bit `b` of `x` from the most significant to the less significant, one by one, end compare `(x + b) * 10` with `v`. If its smaller or equal to `v`, then the bit `b` is set in `x`. To test the next bit, we simply shift b one position to the right (divide by two).

We can avoid the multiplication by 10 by holding `x * 10` and `b * 10` in other variables.

This yields the following algorithm to divide `v` by 10.

```c
uin16_t x = 0, x10 = 0, b = 0x1000, b10 = 0xA000;
while (b != 0) {
    uint16_t t = x10 + b10;
    if (t <= v) {
        x10 = t;
        x |= b;
    }
    b10 >>= 1;
    b >>= 1;
}
// x = v / 10
```

**Edit:**  to get the algorithm of Kuba Ober which avoids the need of variable `x10` , we can subtract `b10` from `v` and `v10` instead. In this case `x10` isn’t needed anymore. The algorithm becomes

```c
uin16_t x = 0, b = 0x1000, b10 = 0xA000;
while (b != 0) {
    if (b10 <= v) {
        v -= b10;
        x |= b;
    }
    b10 >>= 1;
    b >>= 1;
}
// x = v / 10
```

The loop may be unrolled and the different values of `b` and `b10` may be precomputed as constants.

Comment: Er… this is just long division (yeah, that thing you learnt at primary school) for binary rather than decimal.

Comment: I don't know what you call long division. What I'm sure is that I didn't learn that at school. What I learn at school is a different method.

Comment: I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Method , but where the method asks you to “obtain the largest whole number that is a multiple of the divisor”, just keep in mind that the multiple can only be 1 or 0 when working in base-2. Your test for `b10 <= v` is just checking if said multiple is 1.

In any case, this is how I taught long division for a Computer Systems Architecture course some years ago. What method of decimal long division did you learn at school?

Comment: As a side note, it's objectively _easier_ than decimal long division, as you would never ask yourself e.g. “how many times does 3 divide 8?”—in base-2, it either does exactly once with no remainder, or it doesn't at all. The only thing making this less intuitive is our relative familiarity with base-10, in contrast to working in base-2.

Answer (score 3):

On architectures that can only shift one place at a time, a series of explicit comparisons against decreasing powers of two multiplied by 10 might work better than the solution form hacker's delight. Assuming a 16 bit dividend:

```c
uint16_t div10(uint16_t dividend) {
  uint16_t quotient = 0;
  #define div10_step(n) \
    do { if (dividend >= (n*10)) { quotient += n; dividend -= n*10; } } while (0)
  div10_step(0x1000);
  div10_step(0x0800);
  div10_step(0x0400);
  div10_step(0x0200);
  div10_step(0x0100);
  div10_step(0x0080);
  div10_step(0x0040);
  div10_step(0x0020);
  div10_step(0x0010);
  div10_step(0x0008);
  div10_step(0x0004);
  div10_step(0x0002);
  div10_step(0x0001);
  #undef div10_step
  if (dividend >= 5) ++quotient; // round the result (optional)
  return quotient;
}
```

Comment: Your code performs 16 multiplication by 10. Why do you think your code is faster than hacker’s delight ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think. What matters is whether at the applicable platform it is faster. Try yourself! There's no universally fastest solution here at all. Every solution has some platform in mind, and will work best on that platform, possibly better than any other solution.

Comment: I didn’t notice that n*10 is constant. It will thus be precomputed by the compiler. I provided an alternate algorithm in an answer. Our algorithm are equivalent except for one difference. You subtract b*10 from v and I add it to x*10. Your algorithm doesn’t need to keep track of x*10 which saves a variable. The code you show unrolls the my while loop.

Comment: @chmike: On a machine without hardware multiply, `n*10` is still cheap: `(n<<3) + (n<<1)`.  These small-shift answers could maybe be useful on machines with slow or non-existent HW multiply, and only a shift by 1.  Otherwise a fixed-point inverse is much better for compile-time constant divisors (like modern compilers do for `x/10`).

Comment: This is an awesome solution, especially useful for processors that do not have right shift (e.g. LC-3).

Comment: @ErikEidt: njuffa's answer on [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443307) doesn't need a right-shift either, only an `adc` or unsigned-compare for manual carry detection, and for the actual conditional.

Comment: This is an awesome solution, thank you so much. And I have found if you turn all or some of those ifs into whiles, you can take out some of the intermediate steps and it can still be quite efficient leaving every 4th step or so. Saves a lot of code space for not much increase in cycles. Edit: this is on AVR, where bit shifts by more than one are expensive

Answer (score 2):

Well division is subtraction, so yes.  Shift right by 1 (divide by 2).  Now subtract 5 from the result, counting the number of times you do the subtraction until the value is less than 5.  The result is number of subtractions you did.  Oh, and dividing is probably going to be faster.

A hybrid strategy of shift right then divide by 5 using the normal division might get you a performance improvement if the logic in the divider doesn't already do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [realtime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076173), here's a python-based approach that supports infinite precision:

```py
def bit_div10( n ):
    bl = n.bit_length()
    
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2)
    
    i = 2
    while 1<<i < bl:
        q += (q >> (1<<i))
        i += 1
    
    q = q >> 3
    r = n - (((q << 2) + q) << 1)
    return q + (r > 9)
```

output:

```py
>>> bit_div10( 1234567891000000 )
123456789100000
>>> bit_div10( 12345678901234567890123456789000000 )
1234567890123456789012345678900000
>>> bit_div10( 12345678901234567890123456789 )
1234567890123456789012345678
```

NOTE: This is not exactly fast, it just works with values that would break most answers here, including the referenced answer.

EDIT: Alternative approach based on [John Källén's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5558614/2131849) which is smaller and potentially faster than the previous code:

```py
def div10( n ):
    l = 2 << int(log2( n.bit_length() ))
    return ( ((sum( 0x33 << (i<<3) for i in range(l >> 3) )>>1)^3) * n) >> l
```

The output is the same as the previous code.

To explain the code a bit, it works via replicating the pattern of `invDivisor` within the range of `l` (`l = 8 << power` based on divisor bit length).

Basically if `n` is 44 bits then l is 64 bits,
where `invDivisor` is calculated as `( 0x3333333333333333 >> 1 ) ^ 3` which results in `0x199999999999999A`.

It works surprisingly well at any bit depth.

Answer (score 1):

For unsigned bytes—numbers less than 256 or 2<sup>8</sup>:

```c
uint8_t divideByTenUint8(uint8_t x) {
    unsigned t = 17 + (unsigned)x + ((unsigned)x << 4);
    return (uint8_t)((t + (t >> 1)) >> 8);
}
```

For unsigned numbers less than 1029 (2<sup>10</sup>+5) (adapted from @AloisKraus's answer):

```c
unsigned divideByTenLt1029(unsigned x) {
    uint_least32_t t = x; // in case of 16-bit ints
    uint_least32_t u = t + (t << 4);
    return (unsigned)((t + (u << 2) + (u << 3)) >> 11);
}
```

For numbers less than 65536 (2<sup>16</sup>):

```c
uint16_t divideByTenUint16(uint16_t x) {
    uint_least32_t t = 257 + (uint_least32_t)x + ((uint_least32_t)x << 8);
    t += t << 4;
    return (uint16_t)((t + (t >> 1)) >> 16);
}
```

For numbers less than 4294967296 (2<sup>32</sup>):

```c
uint32_t divideByTenUint32(uint32_t x) {
    uint_least64_t t = x;
    t += 3 + (t << 4) + (t << 8) + (t << 12);
    return (uint32_t)((t + (t << 1) + (t << 16) + (t << 17)) >> 33);
}
```

For all 64-bit numbers (requires GCC extensions):

```c
uint64_t divideByTenUint64(uint64_t x) {
    __uint128_t t = 1 + (__uint128_t)x;
    t+=t<<32, t+=t<<16, t+=t<<8, t+=t<<4;
    return (uint64_t)((t + (t >> 1)) >> 64);
}
```

Comment: Those last three are probably not more efficient than what compilers do for `x / 10` using a multiplicative inverse. (*[Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935)*). It's not identical, though; the standard algorithm doesn't start with adding a constant.

Comment: @PeterCordes It does not appear so: https://asm-reveal.godbolt.org/z/fGY5o7E35 . None of these bit-shifted versions are as good as the compiler unless you're dealing with a processor with very slow multiplication. On modern x86, full 64-bit multiplication is pipelined and typically has half the throughput of bitwise operators.

Comment: Huh, I'd hoped that GCC would optimize those adds of shifted copies of the input into a multiply by a constant with those bits set.  (i.e. add those partial products.)  It actually does do that for `divideByTenUint16`, with an `imul` by `0x1111`.  But still multiple steps involving right shift.  (Modern x86 `imul` is typically 3c latency, 1c throughput.  vs. `add` and bitwise ops being 4/clock throughput on Haswell / Zen and later with single-cycle latency.  https://uops.info/.)  LEA is also fast, but only has a 2-bit shift count.

Comment: A low-end ARM with a slow multiplier could take good advantage of these with the barrel shifter allowing `add r0, r0, lsr #1` or something instead of x86's `mov` / `shr reg, 1` / `add`.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M,  Cortex-M0/M0+/M23 have a choice of a 1 cycle multiplier vs. a 32 cycle multiplier (producing only a 32-bit result.)  AArch64 could materialize the multiplier constants using a single `orr` instruction since they have a repeated bit-pattern like `0x1111...`

Answer (score 0):

I've designed a new method in AVR assembly, with lsr/ror and sub/sbc only. It divides by 8, then sutracts the number divided by 64 and 128, then subtracts the 1,024th and the 2,048th, and so on and so on. Works very reliable (includes exact rounding) and quick (370 microseconds at 1 MHz).
The source code is here for 16-bit-numbers:
http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/DIV10/div10_16rd.asm
The page that comments this source code is here:
http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/DIV10/DIV10.html
I hope that it helps, even though the question is ten years old.
brgs, gsc

Answer (score -1):

elemakil's comments' code can be found here: https://doc.lagout.org/security/Hackers%20Delight.pdf
page 233. "Unsigned divide by 10 [and 11.]"

Comment: Link-only answers are not what Stack Overflow is about.  If that covers the method described in some other answer, you could leave a comment or make a suggested adit.  But this isn't enough to be an answer on its own.  Alternatively you could quote or summarize some of what it says and highlight the key parts, if that would make a minimal answer even if the link breaks.