# performance of log10 function returning an int

Tags: c++, optimization, integer, logarithm

Today I needed a cheap `log10()` function, of which I only used the int part. Assuming the result is floored, so the `log10()` of 999 would be 2. Would it be beneficial writing a function myself? And if so, which way would be the best to go. Assuming the code would not be optimized.

The alternatives to `log10()` I've though of;

- use a for loop dividing or multiplying by 10;
- use a string parser(probably extremely expensive);
- using an integer `log2()` function multiplying by a constant.

Comment: You need something that is fast, but not optimized, in no particular language.  Good luck with that.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Scott Hunter sorry I didn't explain myself more clearly. I meant compiler optimization. I'm mostly interested in the concept of an efficient log function returning ints.

Comment: If its only integer log you are looking for then have a look at: http://helloacm.com/fast-integer-log10/ and http://rot47.net/share-picture/37. They are essentially the same thing. One in C# and one in C++.

Comment: Hmm... the answers seem to limit to integer *argument* - but I don't see this requirement in the question itself. E.g., it might well be useful to ask for the integral part of the power of 10 for a number like 1.23e-12... especially given the "or *multiplying* by 10" as one of the options considered in the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The operation can be done in (fast) constant time on any architecture that has a count-leading-zeros or similar instruction (which is most architectures).  Here's a C snippet I have sitting around to compute the number of digits in base ten, which is essentially the same task (assumes a gcc-like compiler and 32-bit int):

```
unsigned int baseTwoDigits(unsigned int x) {
    return x ? 32 - __builtin_clz(x) : 0;
}

static unsigned int baseTenDigits(unsigned int x) {
    static const unsigned char guess[33] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8,
        9, 9, 9
    };
    static const unsigned int tenToThe[] = {
        1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 
        1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000,
    };
    unsigned int digits = guess[baseTwoDigits(x)];
    return digits + (x >= tenToThe[digits]);
}
```

GCC and clang compile this down to ~10 instructions on x86.  With care, one can make it faster still in assembly.

The key insight is to use the (extremely cheap) base-two logarithm to get a fast estimate of the base-ten logarithm; at that point we only need to compare against a single power of ten to decide if we need to adjust the guess.  This is much more efficient than searching through multiple powers of ten to find the right one.

If the inputs are overwhelmingly biased to one- and two-digit numbers, a linear scan is sometimes faster; for all other input distributions, this implementation tends to win quite handily.

Comment: + Very nice (assuming the `int` is big enough).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Yes, obviously, this doesn’t extend to arbitrary-precision integers (though it does extend to any “small” fixed-size type).

Comment: I've generalized it for any built-in unsigned integer type: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16f8a901a31b9d73 . You might want to update your code with this.

Comment: I've generalized it for any built-in unsigned integer type AND for any base, not just 10. [Check out the code here.](https://github.com/Eisenwave/voxel-io/blob/master/src/intlog.hpp). This produces highly optimized output with only 10 instructions for `log10floor(unsigned short)`. See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zWE199) for a portable version.

Comment: @Ruslan you should really be using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` for the guess table and not `unsigned`. This step alone has made my code four times faster. I suppose bytes can be accessed much faster than packs of bytes.

Comment: Your implementation is actually not even correct. `baseTenDigits(0)` results in `0`, when it should result in `1`.

Comment: Log of 0 is undefined though, so I guess that can be partially forgiven - or checked against if needed.  Main thought is that is a very nice way to use base2 to get to base10.  Or change the 0 to a 4 in the ? expression and then 0 works.

Comment: Actually, change the first value in `tenToThe` table to `0`, then you can remove the whole ? check for zero from the `baseTwoDigits()`, speeding it up even more and providing 1 for number of digits at 0.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan the method is not called `log10` it is called `baseTenDigits`. It also returns `1` for an input of `1` and `2` for an input of `10`. These are not logarithms.

The edit you suggested would solve the problem though and be consistent with the semantics of the function.

Comment: Whether you consider `0` to have one significant digit or no significant digits maybe subjective or context dependent. For counting characters is a format, both `baseTenDigits` and `baseTwoDigits` should return `1` in that case (unless you format a zero as a blank). In which case `baseTwoDigits` becomes `return x ? 32 - __builtin_clz(x) : 1;` and the same test for zero should be added to `baseTenDigits`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan no you can't remove the ? test because `__builtin_clz(x)` has undefined behaviour if zero is passed into it

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's the old standby - the "poor man's log function".
(If you want to handle more than 63 integer digits, change the first "if" to a "while".)

```
n = 1;
if (v >= 1e32){n += 32; v /= 1e32;}
if (v >= 1e16){n += 16; v /= 1e16;}
if (v >=  1e8){n +=  8; v /=  1e8;}
if (v >=  1e4){n +=  4; v /=  1e4;}
if (v >=  1e2){n +=  2; v /=  1e2;}
if (v >=  1e1){n +=  1; v /=  1e1;}
```

so if you feed in 123456.7, here's how it goes:

```
n = 1;
if (v >= 1e32) no
if (v >= 1e16) no
if (v >=  1e8) no
if (v >=  1e4) yes, so n = 5, v = 12.34567
if (v >=  1e2) no
if (v >=  1e1) yes, so n = 6, v = 1.234567
     so result is n = 6
```

---

Here's a variation that uses multiplication, rather than division:

```
int n = 1;
double d = 1, temp;
temp = d * 1e32; if (v >= temp){n += 32; d = temp;}
temp = d * 1e16; if (v >= temp){n += 16; d = temp;}
temp = d *  1e8; if (v >= temp){n +=  8; d = temp;}
temp = d *  1e4; if (v >= temp){n +=  4; d = temp;}
temp = d *  1e2; if (v >= temp){n +=  2; d = temp;}
temp = d *  1e1; if (v >= temp){n +=  1; d = temp;}
```

and an execution looks like this

```
v = 123456.7
n = 1
d = 1
temp = 1e32, if (v >= 1e32) no
temp = 1e16, if (v >= 1e16) no
temp =  1e8, if (v >=  1e8) no
temp =  1e4, if (v >=  1e4) yes, so n = 5, d = 1e4;
temp =  1e6, if (v >=  1e6) no
temp =  1e5, if (v >=  1e5) yes, so n = 6, d = 1e5;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be loop with subtracting powers of 10. This powers could be computed and stored in table. Here example in python:

```
table = [10**i for i in range(1, 10)]
# [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000]

def fast_log10(n):
    for i, k in enumerate(table):
        if n - k < 0:
           return i
```

Usage example:

```
>>> fast_log10(1)
0
>>> fast_log10(10)
1
>>> fast_log10(100)
2
>>> fast_log10(999)
2
fast_log10(1000)
3
```

Also you may use binary search with this table. Then algorithm complexity would be only O(lg(n)), where n is number of digits.
Here example with binary search in C:

```
long int table[] = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000};
#define TABLE_LENGHT sizeof(table) / sizeof(long int)

int bisect_log10(long int n, int s, int e) {
    int a = (e - s) / 2 + s;
    if(s >= e)
        return s;
    if((table[a] - n) <= 0)
        return bisect_log10(n, a + 1, e);
    else
        return bisect_log10(n, s, a);
}

int fast_log10(long int n){
    return bisect_log10(n, 0, TABLE_LENGHT);
}
```

Note for small numbers this method would slower then upper method.
Full code [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8365745/).

Comment: A linear search is definitely not “the fastest way”.

Comment: This is just O(n), where n is digit count in number. Other suggested ways use division that much slower.

Comment: OK, but O(lg(n)) and O(1) methods that don’t use division exist.

Comment: Can you post link to method that compute floored log with O(1) ?

Comment: @StephenCanon: Right - what's the O(1) method? [unless you consider n < max, in which case all methods are O(1)]

Comment: I don't say that this O(1) method, I just ask post link to O(1) method. He say that O(1) exists so I want to know it.

Comment: @SlavaBacherikov: I know, but if you don't put `@Stephen` in the comment, he may not see it.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: I posted an answer with a division-less constant-time (up to second-order cache effects) implementation.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a faster log function you need to approximate their result. E.g. the exp function can be approximated using a 'short' taylor approximation. You can find example approximations for exp, log, root and power [here](http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/06/fast-approximate-logarithm-exponential.html)

**edit:**
You can find a short performance comparsion [here](http://www.codingforspeed.com/using-faster-exponential-approximation/)

Answer (score 1):

Because an unsigned `<` or `>=` test is done simply by subtracting and checking the carry flag, it is possible to put both arrays (`guess` and negated `tenToThe`) in a single 64-bit value, combine both array lookups into one, and use the carry from 32-bit addition to adjust the guess.  The high 32 bits of `guess[n]` provide the value of log10(2^n*2-1), while the low 32 bits contain `-10^log10(2^n*2-1)`.

```c
static unsigned int baseTwoDigits(unsigned int x) {
    return x ? 32 - __builtin_clz(x) : 0;
}

unsigned int baseTenDigits(unsigned int x) {
    static uint64_t guess[33] = {
      /* 1 */         0, 0, 0, 
      /* 8 */         (1ull<<32)-10, (1ull<<32)-10, (1ull<<32)-10, 
      /* 64 */        (2ull<<32)-100, (2ull<<32)-100, (2ull<<32)-100, 
      /* 512 */       (3ull<<32)-1000, (3ull<<32)-1000, (3ull<<32)-1000, 
                      (3ull<<32)-1000, 
      /* 8192 */      (4ull<<32)-10000, (4ull<<32)-10000, (4ull<<32)-10000, 
      /* 65536 */     (5ull<<32)-100000, (5ull<<32)-100000, (5ull<<32)-100000, 
      /* 524288 */    (6ull<<32)-1000000, (6ull<<32)-1000000, (6ull<<32)-1000000, 
                      (6ull<<32)-1000000, 
      /* 8388608 */   (7ull<<32)-10000000, (7ull<<32)-10000000,
                      (7ull<<32)-10000000, 
      /* 67108864 */  (8ull<<32)-100000000, (8ull<<32)-100000000, 
                      (8ull<<32)-100000000, 
      /* 536870912 */ (9ull<<32)-1000000000, (9ull<<32)-1000000000, 
                      (9ull<<32)-1000000000, 
    };
    uint64_t adjust = guess[baseTwoDigits(x)];
    return (adjust + x) >> 32;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Space-optimized version of [StephenCanon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25934909/10871073), `uint32_t` only. Uses a single LUT of 16 bytes and properly handles `0`.

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse)
#endif

static inline unsigned msb(const unsigned x)
{
    unsigned lz;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    (void) _BitScanReverse(&lz, x);
#else
    lz = __builtin_clz(x);
#endif
    return ((sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT) - 1) - lz;
}

static unsigned b10digits(const uint32_t x)
{
    static const uint16_t lut[8] = { 0, 2, 13, 69, 347, 1736, 8680, 43402 };
    const unsigned
        shr = (msb(x | 1) & ((sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT) - 2)) << 1,
        dig = (0x8877665433221100ull >> shr) & 0xF,
        val = lut[(0x07D63440u >> (dig * 3)) & 0x7],
        p10 = ((val << dig) + (~((unsigned)-1 << dig) & 0xC7)) * 90 + 10;
    return dig + (x >= p10 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without any specifications, I will just give a general answer:

The log function will be pretty efficient in most languages as it is such a basic function.

The fact that you are only interested in integers could give you some leverage, but probably this is not enough to easily beat the builtin standard solutions.

One of the few things that I can think of to be faster than a builtin function is a table lookup, so if you are only interested in the numbers upto 10000 for instance, you could simply create a table that you could use to lookup any of these values when you need them.

Obviously this solution will not scale well, but it may be just what you need.

---

Sidenote: If you are importing the data for example, it may actually be faster to look at the string diecty length (rather than first converting the string to a number and than looking at the value of the string). Of course this will require the input to be stored in just the right format, otherwise it won't gain you anything.