# How can you quickly compute the integer logarithm for any base?

Tags: c++, math, c++17, radix, logarithm

How can I quickly compute the integer logarithm for any base, not just base 10? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25934909) has a really efficient solution for base 10 but I would like to understand how I can generalize that to other bases.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Fundamentals

The logarithm base `b` of any number `n` `log_b(n)` can be computed using `log(n) / log(b)` where `log` is the logarithm with any base (usually the natural logarithm). `log(b)` is a constant, so if we can compute the logarithm for some base efficiently, we can compute the logarithm for *any* base efficiently.

Unfortunately, this conversion is only possible if we don't drop digits. For integers, we can only quickly compute the floored logarithm. For example, `log_2(10) = 3`. This would be the result for any number between 8 and 15, despite those having different amounts of decimal digits. So this binary logarithm can help us make a good guess, but we need to refine that guess.

### Base 10

The aforementioned question has the following solution:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned log2floor(uint64_t x) {
    // implementation for C++17 using clang or gcc
    return x ? 63 - __builtin_clzll(x) : 0;

    // implementation using the new C++20 <bit> header
    return x ? 63 - std::countl_zero(x) : 0;
}

constexpr unsigned log10floor(unsigned x) {
    constexpr unsigned char guesses[32] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8,
        9, 9
    };
    constexpr uint64_t powers[11] = {
        1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000,
        10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000
    };
    unsigned guess = guesses[log2floor(x)];
    return guess + (x >= powers[guess + 1]);
}
```

Note that I had to make some modifications because the solution isn't actually 100% correct.

As explained in the question, we make a guess based on the binary logarithm which can be computed very efficiently and then increment our guess if necessary.

The guess table can be computed using:

```cpp
index -> log_10(exp(2, index)) = log_10(1 << index)
```

You can see that the table first has a `1` entry at index `4`, because `exp(2, 4) = 16` which has a floored `log_10` of `1`.

### Example

Say we want to know the `log_10(15)`:

1. We compute `log_2(15) = 3`
2. We lookup `log_10(exp(2, 3)) = log_10(8) = 0`. This is our initial guess.
3. We lookup `exp(10, guess + 1) = exp(10, 1) = 10`.
4. `15 >= 10`, so our guess was too low and we return `guess + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1` instead.

### Generalization for any Base

To generalize this approach for any base, we must compute the lookup tables in a `constexpr` context. To compute the guess table, we need a naive logarithm implementation for any base first:

```cpp
template <typename Uint>
constexpr Uint logFloor_naive(Uint val, unsigned base)  {
    Uint result = 0;
    while (val /= base) {
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, we can compute the lookup tables:

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <array>

template <typename Uint, size_t BASE>
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, std::numeric_limits<Uint>::digits> makeGuessTable()
{
    decltype(makeGuessTable<Uint, BASE>()) result{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        Uint pow2 = static_cast<Uint>(Uint{1} << i);
        result.data[i] = logFloor_naive(pow2, BASE);
    }
    return result;
}

// The maximum possible exponent for a given base that can still be represented
// by a given integer type.
// Example: maxExp<uint8_t, 10> = 2, because 10^2 is representable by an 8-bit unsigned
// integer but 10^3 isn't.
template <typename Uint, unsigned BASE>
constexpr Uint maxExp = logFloor_naive<Uint>(static_cast<Uint>(~Uint{0u}), BASE);

// the size of the table is maxPow<Uint, BASE> + 2 because we need to store the maximum power
// +1 because we need to contain it, we are dealing with a size, not an index
// +1 again because for narrow integers, we access guess+1
template <typename Uint, size_t BASE>
constexpr std::array<uint64_t, maxExp<Uint, BASE> + 2> makePowerTable()
{
    decltype(makePowerTable<Uint, BASE>()) result{};
    uint64_t x = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i, x *= BASE) {
        result.data[i] = x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that we need the `maxExp` templated constant to determine the size of the second lookup table. Finally, we can use the lookup tables to come up with the final function:

```cpp
// If our base is a power of 2, we can convert between the
// logarithms of different bases without losing any precision.
constexpr bool isPow2or0(uint64_t val) {
    return (val & (val - 1)) == 0;
}

template <size_t BASE = 10, typename Uint>
constexpr Uint logFloor(Uint val) {
    if constexpr (isPow2or0(BASE)) {
        return log2floor(val) / log2floor(BASE);
    }
    else {
        constexpr auto guesses = makeGuessTable<Uint, BASE>();
        constexpr auto powers = makePowerTable<Uint, BASE>();

        uint8_t guess = guesses[log2floor(val)];
        
        // Accessing guess + 1 isn't always safe for 64-bit integers.
        // This is why we need this condition. See below for more details.
        if constexpr (sizeof(Uint) < sizeof(uint64_t)
            || guesses.back() + 2 < powers.size()) {
            return guess + (val >= powers[guess + 1]);
        }
        else {
            return guess + (val / BASE >= powers[guess]);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes on the `powers` Lookup Table

The reason why we always use `uint64_t` for our `powers` table is that we access `guess + 1` and `exp(10, guess + 1)` isn't always representable. For example, if we are using 8-bit integers and have a guess of `2`, then `exp(10, guess + 1)` would be `1000` which is not representable using an 8-bit integer.

Usually, this causes a problem for 64-bit integers, because there is no larger integer type available. But there are exceptions. For example, the largest power of 2 which is representable, `exp(2, 63)` is lower than `exp(10, 19)`, which is the largest representable power of 10. This means that the highest guess will be `18` and `exp(10, guess + 1) = exp(10, 19)` is representable. Therefore, we can always safely access `powers[guess + 1]`.

These exceptions are very useful because we can avoid an integer division in such cases. As seen above, exceptions like this can be detected with:

```cpp
guesses.back() + 2 < powers.size()
```

Comment: Instead of `__builtin_clzll`, you can also use functions from [`<bit>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) (C++20): [`countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) or [`bit_width`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width).

Comment: In MSVC you can use a similar intrinsic in __lzcnt64 (assuming your cpu supports the LZCNT instruction)