# Calculating log using bitwise

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, logarithm

Using `std::__builtin_ctzll()` in C++ I can easily calculate `log2(x)`. But can I calculate `log3(x)` and `log5(x)` using bitwise ?

Comment: well `log5(x) == log2(x)/log2(5)` so if you have `log2` then you can calculate `log3` and `log5` but you don't truly have `log2`, you just have the number of `0` bits as an integer?

Comment: Are you sure `ctz` (count *trailing* zeroes) can be used to compute `log2`? As far as I know only `clz` (count *leading* zeroes) can be used to compute `floor(log2(x)) == sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - clz(x)`. Note the `floor` which would heavily distort the approach `log2(x) / log2(anyBase)`. Maybe you can iteratively clear the highest bit to compute the missing fractional digits. However, such a loop would probably be slower than using the builtin `log`.

Comment: FYI: [SO: How can you quickly compute the integer logarithm for any base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63411054/7478597)