# Calculating decimal exponent of double quickly and accurately

Tags: c, performance, math, double

edit: To clarify, by "decimal exponent of a double" I mean the magnitude of the value or the base 10 exponent of the value. For instance 3456.7 -> 3.4567E3 -> Scientific Exponent = 3

I need to find the decimal exponent of a double.

I've been researching ways this is done, and I've found various methods.

For instance to estimate the exponent Microsoft's STL uses an [interesting lookup table](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/60f18856c56389001c38a9929ef37bd5c01c4e47/stl/inc/charconv#L2400):

However, the method I came up with seems the simplest:

```
  // v -> value
  // x -> ScientificExponent
  // 10^x <= v < 10^(x+1)
  // x <= log(v) < x+1

  ScientificExponent = (Value == 0) ? 1 : floor((log10(fabs(Value))));
```

I'm wondering why this isn't used. Are there cases where this doesn't work? Is this assumed to be too slow?

Are there any edge/corner cases I am not considering (maybe subnormal values being too small to get an accurate log calculation from)?

I'd appreciate any insight people can provide.

Also, if this is a good way to do this, is there a good way to calculate only the integer part of log10? It seems a waste to calculate the log to many decimal places only to throw it away with the `floor`.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892665/performance-of-log10-function-returning-an-int

Comment: That answers the last question in my post, thanks! I'm still wondering about why this method isn't used for exponent estimation, what the drawbacks/advantages are, and if this is a viable method

Comment: It's generally safe to assume that the method used in common libraries is chosen for performance reasons. We've had decades to determine the optimal method.

Comment: That LUT in STL is optimized for determining only if it is within the fixed point range so it's not suitable for all of my applications anyway. If you could provide another method that has been optimized for this that would be great! I haven't been able to find any "accepted" solution for this

Comment: If you have floating-point inputs then the standard [`frexp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp) function might be of interest to you.  That will quickly and easily get you the exponent of the *base-2* exponential notation (of the form 0.1xxxxxE+-n).

Comment: @AdamBujak "quickly and accurately" --> which is more important? speed or accuracy?

Comment: @AdamBujak "I need to find the decimal exponent of a double."  --> This deserves greater detail as to **why**.  Even if you had an good way to do this, what higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor((log10(fabs(Value))))` is inadequate to compute the decimal exponent of a number.

Consider using IEEE-754 binary64 (“double precision”). Let `Value` be 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625 = 9.999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625•10<sup>−2</sup>, which is a representable value.

log<sub>10</sub> of 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625 is approximately ?−1.000000000000000036162279995748268157562864421389843161585017393347605917054938808868324457086236340. This number is not representable in binary64; the closest representable value is −1.

So a good `log10` implementation will return −1 for input 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625.

Then `floor((log10(fabs(Value))))` produces −1, but the correct result would be −2.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to where I could find a better solution?

Comment: @AdamBujak: Converting floating-point to decimal efficiently is notoriously “hard.” References to some information are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153979/algorithm-to-convert-an-ieee-754-double-to-a-string). I do not know to what extent reducing it to the sub-problem of obtaining only the exponent simplifies the task.

Answer (score 0):

Without `math.h`!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIGITS 16

int decimal_exponent(double v)
{
  int len = DIGITS + 6, e;
  char buffer[len];

  sprintf(buffer, "%1.*e", DIGITS, v);
  sscanf(buffer + DIGITS + 3, "%i", &e);

  return e;
}

int main(void)
{
  double v = 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625;
  printf("%i\n", decimal_exponent(v));
  return 0;
}
```

running:

```
$ ./exp 
-2
```

Yes, it's a joke

Comment: `+ 3` is the wrong offset with negative values.  Rather than `DIGITS 16`, consider `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1`.  Yes, it's a joke

Answer (score 0):

When `Value` is near a power-of-10, the rounding in `log10(Value)` leads to values just smaller than a power-of-10 rounding up to the result to the next integer.

Code needs to use extended precession math *somehow*.

When `...printf()` is well coded, we could use its extended math.  Use enough precision to avoid rounding up to the next whole number.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int decimal_exponenet(double x) {
  assert(isfinite(x));
  //       -   d   .        ddddddd            e   -  expo  \0
  char buf[1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1) + 1 + 1 + 10 + 1];
  sprintf(buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1, x);
  char *e = strchr(buf, 'e');
  assert(e);
  return atoi(e + 1);
}
```

For `|Value| < 1.0`, we have the additional problem that `Value` is not an *exact* power of 10.  The above may still round in a undesired fashion for some extreme `double` encoding.  More precision would help then.  For common `double`, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 2` significant digits is sufficient.

---

> Are there any edge/corner cases I am not considering

`+/-0.0, +/-infinity, NAN` deserve special attention.  I would not expect subnormals to be an issue, but testing should include those.