# How to convert a number to a alphanumeric using bitwise in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have written a program that will convert a number into string. The core logic is using
% 10. However, I am looking for some other way. The other way should be using bitwise operator. The first question comes to my mind is how to split the digits using bitwise operation. I am unable to think on those lines. Here is my usual program.

```
   #include "stdio.h"

void itoaperChar(int n, char *s)
{
    s[0] = '0' + n;

    s[1] = '\0';
}

typedef struct my_string
{
    char val;
    struct my_string *next;
}my_string;

void convertitoString(int nu, char *des)
{
    char tempChar[2];
    my_string *Head = NULL;
    my_string *tempNode = NULL;

    while( nu != 0)
    {
        /** when we apply the logic of traversing from last, the data is accessed as LIFO **/
        /** we are again applying LIFO to make it FIFO **/
        int temp = nu%10;
        itoaperChar(temp,&tempChar);
        if(Head == NULL )
        {
            Head =(my_string*)malloc(sizeof(my_string));

            /**  Remember, strcpy looks for \0 in the source string. Always, ensure that the string is null terminated. Even if the string is just 1 byte.**/
            strcpy(&(Head->val),tempChar);
            Head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tempNode = (my_string*)malloc(sizeof(my_string));
            strcpy(&(tempNode->val),tempChar);
            tempNode->next = Head;
            Head = tempNode;
        }

        nu = (nu - temp)/10;

    }

    int lcindex = 0;

    while(Head!=NULL)
    {

        strcpy(&(des[lcindex]),&(Head->val));
        lcindex++;
        tempNode = Head;
        Head=Head->next;
        free(tempNode);
        tempNode = NULL;
    }

    des[lcindex] = '\0';

}

void main()
{
    char t[10];
    convertitoString(1024,t);
    printf("The value of t is %s ", t);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.  (Also, you seem to have forgotten to close a comment block.)

Comment: Give this one some time - I suspect interesting answers.

Comment: I suspect a lot of face hitting desk and moving onto another question ...

Comment: Why do you say that they will hit their face at desk?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Why would you be looking for a way to do this with bitwise operations?  I would start by looking for a way to do the %10 version without creating a linked list and using strcpy to move 1 character strings around.  YIKES!

Comment: Yes, base 10 only. It is not a homework. I was thinking whether it is possible by bitwise or not. Because this modulus by 10 is what I have used in my 9th grade. Now, I am 31 years old. I don't know whether there is some other possibility or not? Or, I have just stuck with my conventional method. Looks like modulus is only the way.

Comment: "other way should be using bitwise operator".  Does this mean no adding? (as in `lcindex++;`) or arithmetic comparisons?.  Otherwise the double dabble algorithm suggested by @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc looks good.  A solution exist that only uses `| & << >> `, small table look-up.  See [Binary-to-BCD Converter p. 8](http://www.utm.edu/~leeb/DM74185.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your code since it's so badly indented, but why making it so complex like that? A number-to-string program that uses divide-by-10 can take only a few (tens of) lines

If your want to do it with only bitwise operation, you can use [double dabble algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble). It converts a number from binary to BCD with only bitwise operations. The conversion from BCD to string is just an expansion from packed nibbles to 2 character bytes

Comment: That's cool, but the double dabble algorithm still involves arithmetic operations in addition to the bitwise ones.  I guess I really don't understand what the OP is after...

Comment: @pat there's almost no way to do complex arithmetics with only bitwise operations. You can replace additions and subtractions with software adders but that'll make the function slows down seriously

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is an arithmetic operator based on division; it's fundamentally an arithmetic operator, not a bitwise operator. Unless the modulus is a power of 2 — which it is not here — there is no simple way to implement it in terms of bitwise operators. Sorry.

Comment: technically it's difficult to do a division using only bitwise operators, but it's not impossible. It's much easier if you want to divide by a constant like 10 like this, by [multiplying with the multiplicative inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558492/995714)

Comment: @phuclv While that’s a handy trick, multiplication isn’t a bitwise operation either.