# How can i change mod with bitwise AND

Tags: c

> How can i make:
>
> `x % 10`
>
> `x / 10`
>
> with bitwise & and bitshifting?
>
> Thank you!

Comment: Have you done % 8 and / 8? That's quite simple. A number that isn't a power of 2 is much harder (not sure it's possible with just those two operators - I think you need NAND).

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: I have to translate my C-Programm into assembler language. And now i would change this, because it is simpler to translate this.

Comment: Why don't you compile a program that uses those operations and look at the assembly code produced to see how it is done?

Comment: Which assembler? Doesn't it have an integer division instruction?

Comment: With some extra addition/subtraction it works quite well but only bitwise "and" and bit-shift? What about a "not"? Can we have one? Because a lot is possible with just a handful of "nand" gates!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts

Comment: No. That is why i want to change this.

Comment: i have bitwise "and","xor","left shift" and "right shift"

Comment: and i have ADD and SUB

Comment: @KeineLust Looks like duplicate...

Comment: @Abc in that case let me point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts where your question gets answered.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't want to close it as duplicate because OP is also asking for MOD 10 and the link is not answering this point.

Comment: does somebody has any ideas?

Comment: You've got the link to the answer. Twice!

Comment: @KeineLust I will then. `x % 10 = x - (x / 10) * 10`.

Comment: But not `mod`, sorry! To get the remainder you do `mod = x - ((x / z) * z)`. Multiplication with 10 can be done in that way:   `y = (x << 3) + (x << 1)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure! But I think OP wants to do this using bitwise ops.