# The most efficient way to get the first number of an integer in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, integer

**Description of problem**

I need to get the first number from a given integer. This operation will be done millions of times, therefore I need to make sure that I use the most efficient way of doing this.

If the length of the integer affects the answer, then in my case I know that the integer will always be a 2 digit number.

**What I tried**

I have tried the methods mentioned below. Method 1 and 2 seems slow since I have to convert back and forth. Method 3 uses //, ** and % which I could assume are also heavy on the system. Is there a better way of performing this seemingly "simple" task?

```
# Method 1:
first_digit = int(str(x)[0])

# Method 2:
first_digit = int(str(x)[1:])

# Method 3:
first_digit = x // 10 % 10
```

Comment: if doing this millions of times might be better to use numpy over vanilla python

Comment: Did you try and do any timing of these different options? Are you sure that this will be a bottleneck in whatever you're going to use it, and that you're not trying to prematurely optimize?

Comment: Have you actually timed a million such operations?

Comment: I tried to time it now with the functions separated and it runs for a long time. But when I get the actually numbers out it says 0.0 which is weird. However, I tried using cProfile and then it told me that the operator int(str(x)[1:]) was amongst the 5 largest time consumers of my code, therefore my question.

Comment: I advise you to give a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts if you plan to use Numpy, Numba, Cython or PyPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number has never more than 2 digits the `% 10` is useless. But could it have a single digit as well ? In that case the result would be zero which is wrong. So, assumed that the number is never more than 2 digits, the formula could be :

```
if x > 9: 
    return x // 10;
return x
```

Comment: Not faster, but more concise: `return x if x < 10 else x // 10`

Answer (score 2):

I used `timeit` module to time your methods as well as [dspr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388754/7862940) on 10 million repeats :

```py
from timeit import timeit

n = 10000000
print(timeit(stmt='import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = int(str(n)[0])', number=n))
print(timeit(stmt='import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = int(str(n)[1:])', number=n))
print(timeit(stmt='import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = n // 10 % 10', number=n))
print(timeit(stmt='import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = n//10 if n>9 else n', number=n))
```

which gave me the following results :

```
10.7325472
11.0877854
8.493264900000003
8.550117300000004
```

It seems that `x // 10 % 10` method is a little bit faster than the others.

Comment: the same (for 100000 only) on https://repl.it/languages/python3 gives 1.6996094920032192
0.9015585849992931
0.7443572329939343
0.5641695599915693

Comment: The timing include the generation of the random number and the import which are much slower. Thus, the timings are not very accurate.

Comment: You're right. With a fixed integer (x = 57), I get these results on an iMac i7 4ghz : 5.5298409462
5.52825784683
0.631176948547
0.556658983231 while the first was more than 19ms using a random number

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, the timings are not accurate but the __relative__ timings between methods are, as both import et number generation statements appear in all the `timeit` calls. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @BastienBroussard Not really. On my machine `import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = n // 10 % 10` gives 5.23 while `import random; n = random.randint(10, 99); x = n // 10 % 10; y = n // 10 % 10` gives 5.54. We expect the second result to be twice the first. The variation of the random generation might be significant compared to the computation of `x`. As a result, you cannot be sure `n // 10 % 10` is faster than `n//10 if n>9 else n` statistically speaking because of the very slight gap between the two last timings. I advise to use the `setup` argument of `timeit`.

Comment: How is "n // 10 % 10" faster than "n // 10"?? Is it the if condition? Because I know that all my integers are of length 2.