# BCD math routines instead of using division and modulo (using MSP430F427 MCU)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, msp430, bcd

I am using MSP430F427 MCU, I have this code below to extract, ones digit (d5), tens digit (d4), and hundreds digit (d3). I am expecting a 4-digit value, like 1000+, but have to display only 3-digit (hundreds, tens, ones). i.e count = 1783, I have to display only the 783. The code below works already.

However, during compilation there is a warning to get rid of division and modulo operation when doing this as this is power intensive.
(**Description  Resource    Path    Location (ULP 5.1) Detected modulo operation(s). Recommend moving them to RAM during run time or not using as these are processing/power intensive**)

```
void updateDisplay(signed long counter_value) {

    if (count<0)
    {
        NEG_ON;
    }

    else
    {
        NEG_OFF;
    }

    D3_NULL;
    D4_NULL;
    D5_NULL;

    // Ensure that counter_value is positive or zero for further processing
    counter_value = abs(counter_value);

    // Display the appropriate digit on the LCD based on the count value
    uint8_t d3= (counter_value/100)%10;
    uint8_t d4= (counter_value/10)%10;
    uint8_t d5= counter_value%10;

    if (d3 != 0)
    {
        switch (d3)
        {
            case 1: DIGIT3_DISP_1; break;
            case 2: DIGIT3_DISP_2; break;
            case 3: DIGIT3_DISP_3; break;
            case 4: DIGIT3_DISP_4; break;
            case 5: DIGIT3_DISP_5; break;
            case 6: DIGIT3_DISP_6; break;
            case 7: DIGIT3_DISP_7; break;
            case 8: DIGIT3_DISP_8; break;
            case 9: DIGIT3_DISP_9; break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DIGIT3_OFF;
    }

    if (d4 != 0 || d3 != 0)
    {
        switch (d4)
        {
            case 0: DIGIT4_DISP_0; break;
            case 1: DIGIT4_DISP_1; break;
            case 2: DIGIT4_DISP_2; break;
            case 3: DIGIT4_DISP_3; break;
            case 4: DIGIT4_DISP_4; break;
            case 5: DIGIT4_DISP_5; break;
            case 6: DIGIT4_DISP_6; break;
            case 7: DIGIT4_DISP_7; break;
            case 8: DIGIT4_DISP_8; break;
            case 9: DIGIT4_DISP_9; break;
        }
    }

    else if (d3 != 0)
    {
        DIGIT4_DISP_0;
    }

    switch (d5)
    {
        case 0: DIGIT5_DISP_0; break;
        case 1: DIGIT5_DISP_1; break;
        case 2: DIGIT5_DISP_2; break;
        case 3: DIGIT5_DISP_3; break;
        case 4: DIGIT5_DISP_4; break;
        case 5: DIGIT5_DISP_5; break;
        case 6: DIGIT5_DISP_6; break;
        case 7: DIGIT5_DISP_7; break;
        case 8: DIGIT5_DISP_8; break;
        case 9: DIGIT5_DISP_9; break;
    }
}
```

I want to learn how to save a single digit to a variable. i.e count 674 so d3 = 6, d4 = 7, and d5 = 4. This is what I think I should do. However, I am a bit sluggish in implementing bit shifting and bitwise operation to change the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's an algorithm that works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXIfZ1yKFlA BUT, you'll also need to figure out how to isolate the lowest 3 decimal digits before starting (ie: modulo 1000)... Hope this help is really appreciated... (You'll also have to figure out how to unpack the digits from the 3 'nibbles'...) The way to become less _sluggish_ is to tax yourself and write your own code.

Comment: As this is just a warning, do you have requirements on a zero-warning policy, or on a maximum power consumption? If not, simply ignore it, or try the other suggested solution: move the calculation to RAM.

Comment: the variable is named "counter", you have BCD in the title your code has nothing to do with BCD.  But if you are actually counting you could count BCD style and encode the number that way then you shift and mask and no division nor modulo needed.   This is an incomplete question in that regard.

Comment: can display in binary or octal or hex and let the user convert it. or just learn another number base. lol

Comment: OT: Your code looks pretty convoluted. Are all those `DIGITx_DISP_y`s macros?

Comment: Is switching to a string format possible? That would allow much quicker parsing. Although surely division can't be _that_ bad? How many ticks is a `div` instruction or whatever MSP430 might name it?

Comment: "Recommend moving them to RAM during run time" is also a fishy recommendation. Low to mid-range MCUs shouldn't have flash wait states and the like. So why would moving something to RAM result in faster execution? Including the overhead of copying the code there.

Comment: @Lundin : Quite bad: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa329a/slaa329a.pdf  it has no hardware multiply or divide!  And what is the bet that any library integer to string conversion will use divide hidden from the static analyser?

Comment: @Clifford Ah right so it is software division, yeah that's bad. What I mean with "is string format possible" is that if they can change the original data to a string, since indeed int-to-string conversion likely contains division in itself. You _could_ implement a counter such as `char counter[4+1]="0000";` then increment it by `counter[3]++; if(counter[3]>'9') { counter[3]='0'; counter[2]++; /* and so on */ }` Subtract `'0'` per array item et voilà: BCD. Or just skip the string format if you don't need to print it anywhere.

Comment: The warning is issued by the [ULP advisor](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/ccs_ulp_advisor.html) rather than from the compiler.  You should treat it as advisory and if Ultra-Low Power operation is not a requirement for your project you should probably switch it off.  You might even test power consumption with and without this code.  After all you are driving a display, which is likely to consume orders of magnitude more power than these operations - you may be _sweating the small stuff_.

Comment: @Lundin - yes a direct BCD counter is a good idea - need not even be a string as from the code there is a conversion from digit value to display code in any case.  If of course `counter_value` is indeed just a counter and you do not need to perform other arithmetic on it.  Although BCD arithmetic is not so bad perhaps.  That however would be the question the OP has not asked.  May be an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```c
unsigned divu10( unsigned n) 
{
    unsigned q, r;
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - (((q << 2) + q) << 1);
    return q + (r > 9);
}
```

(From [Divide by 10 using bit shifts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts))

And noting that MSP430 also lacks a hardware multiplier so also:

```c
unsigned mulu10( unsigned multiplicand )
{
    return (multiplicand << 3) + (multiplicand  << 1) ;
}
```

then:

```c
uint8_t* toBCD( unsigned value, uint8_t* bcd, size_t digits )
{
    for( size_t i = digits - 1; 
         i >= 0 && value != 0; 
         i-- )
    {
        unsigned a = divu10( value ) ;
        bcd[i] = value - mulu10( a ) ;
        value = a ;
    }

    return bcd ;
}
```

You can get the least significant three digits on a value in BCD as follows:

```c
uint8_t bcd[3] ;
toBCD( abs(counter_value), bcd, sizeof(bcd) ) ;
```

Then (if you really must):

```
uint8_t d3= bcd[0] ;
uint8_t d4= bcd[1] ;
uint8_t d5= bcd[2] ;
```

But that really has no particular benefit over simply using the `bcd` digits directly e.g.:

```c
switch( bcd[0] )
    ...
```

Whether that is truly more power efficient that using `%` and `/` operators would require testing. The operators are *generalised* whereas these functions are *specialised* for multiply/divide by 10, so likely to generate less code even without resorting to assembly.  I would expect a reasonable compiler to generate near optimal code for such simple operations.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to make use of the fact that 0 <= n < 10,000 but using 16 bit arithmetic which I believe your processor performs. Hopefully it will generate more efficient machine instructions than using longs or even ints. I've borrowed Clifford's divu10 function, but one of the lines can be omitted saving a few operations on each division.

```
uint16_t counter_value16 = abs(counter_value);
uint16_t temp = divu10(counter_value16);
uint8_t d5 = counter_value16 - (temp << 1) - (temp << 3);
uint16_t temp2 = divu10(temp);
uint8_t d4 = temp - (temp2 << 1) - (temp2 << 3);
temp = divu10(temp2);
uint8_t d3 = temp2 - (temp << 1) - (temp << 3);
```

where the following line can safely be commented out.

```
uint16_t divu10(uint16_t n) 
{
    uint16_t q, r;
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    //q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - (((q << 2) + q) << 1);
    return q + (r > 9);
}
```

I posted a 'double dabble' function earlier which you can see in the edit history but its performance is terrible, which was surprising as I thought that algorithm was often used for BCD. Maybe that was the algorithm you were thinking of when you asked the question, but I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: MSP430 has no hardware multiply or divide.  He will still get the warning.

Comment: Multiplying by 10 is trivial as you showed in your answer. Your divide by 10 is for int not long as counter_value is long. I thought it was neater and safer to let the compiler figure it out.

Comment: The `counter_value` is stated to be "_a 4-digit value_", so `long` is unnecessary in this case.  Moreover in the OP code it is re-assigned from `abs()` which returns `int` (unless C++ compilation is used).  My solution uses types _appropriate to the problem_ and is quite deliberate on my part - the OP should take note.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of "Double Dabble" binary to BCD for 16 bit unsigned integers. It's composed of a number of mask and shift operations with easy stuff like adding two values. No need to "divide by 10, multiply by 10, then subtract" to isolate each decimal digit.

SO, it seems, IS a free code writing service sometimes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void toBCD( uint16_t val ) {
    const int decSize = 10; // big enough for "65535"
    char decDgt[ decSize ] = { 0 }; // decimal digits as binary 'nibbles'.
    int curPow10 = 0;

    for( uint16_t bit = 0x8000; bit; bit >>= 1 ) {

        for( int ii = curPow10; ii >= 0; ii-- ) {
            if( decDgt[ ii ] >= 5 ) // "dabble" algorithm step
                decDgt[ ii ] += 3;

            decDgt[ ii ] <<= 1; // "double" algorithm step

            if( decDgt[ ii ] & 0x10 ) { // Carry high bit?
                decDgt[ ii + 1 ] |= 0x1;
                if( ii == curPow10 ) // new power of 10?
                    curPow10++;
                decDgt[ ii ] &= 0xF; // dealing in 'nibbles'
            }
        }
        decDgt[ 0 ] |= ( ( val & bit ) != 0 ); // truth value 0 or 1
    }

    for( int ii = curPow10; ii >= 0; ii-- )
        putchar( decDgt[ ii ] + '0' );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) {
    toBCD( 0x000F );
    toBCD( 0x00FF );
    toBCD( 0x0100 );
    toBCD( 0x0401 );
    toBCD( 0x1000 );
    toBCD( 0xFFFF );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15
255
256
1025
4096
65535
```

Note: Base10 digits are accumulated in reverse order in the array (that is NOT null terminated.) Notice how they are retrieved and converted to ASCII digits. (This is a stripped down version of a version that handled Base2 values of as many bits/bytes as were desired.) Ignoring digits above "999" and prepending leading zeros, if required, is left as an exercise for the OP.