# Is it possible to make x%10 (modulus 10) with bitwise operators in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, modulo

I've been trying to search this specific answer here on SO and other websites, but I haven't got any clear answer so far.
Is it possible to find the last digit of an integer as of `x % 10` using bitwise operators?

In my code I have something like `rand() % 10` and I wanted to know if is there anything I could to make it as a bitwise operation, in fewer lines possible.

I know  that if you have an hexadecimal number, you can do this by the following:
`0xABCDE & 0xF == E`
`0xABCD & 0xF == D`
`and so on...`
However, this would result in a range bigger than 10. Since I'm using a random number generator, I would like to have all these operations in the range `from 0 to 9.` Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod10

Comment: 1. Why does the modulo operator hurt you? -- 2. Let's pretend for a moment that such a bitwise operator exists and let's define it as `#`. Please [edit] your question and show the existing and the new expression in its complete statement. Currently I fail to see how `value % 10` can be expressed shorter.

Comment: @thebusybee I think by "in fewer lines possible", OP means "in as few lines as possible". The motivation might have to do with speed, or perhaps they are asking to see whether one can implement this in the hardware using bit logic.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Thanks, that is most probably the right interpretation, anyway, it is speculation. Therefore, the OP needs to clarify. ;-) We don't even have a clue what target hardware is used.

Comment: 3. The more I think about your problem, the more I feel that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What issue do you really want to solve?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The function mod10() you linked to doesn't work correctly. It fails first at 510.

Comment: Please note that compilers are optimizing your code for you, and they often know best which sequence of instructions to use under the hood to get the result you want. They know how to optimize multiplications and divisions by constants. So I would just write `value % 10` in your code and trust the compiler to do what is best. Note that that still might be a simple division instruction, if that is faster than multiple bitwise instructions. On x86_64, GCC turns the modulo 10 into a multiplication followed by some shift, add and sub instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/qPdcxz5fT

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. Why do you think you need to replace `%` with bitwise operators? Note that `rand() % 10` does not produce an uniform distribution, and any replacement that does the same thing with bitwise operators won't either. If you need a uniform distribution, you need an algorithm that produces a uniform distribution, which `rand() % 10` isn't. If you do *not* need a uniform distribution, consider returning `4` every time.

Comment: One very simple algorithm that produces a uniform distribution in `[0..9]` (assuming `rand()` is uniform and ranges from 0 to 2^k-1) is like that: `int x; while ((x = rand() & 0xF) >= 10; return x;` (and it doesn't use `%`).

Comment: @n.m. Worrying about distribution of random numbers from `rand()` is a bit like finding a rusted-out Yugo in a junkyard and spending half a day waxing it. :-) If you're worried about cryptographic security you wouldn't be using `rand()` in the first place.  If you have enough random bits, even `%` will be *de facto* cryptographically secure if the modulo is small - good luck getting information from the bias in `x` from `uint64_t x = getCryptoSecureRandom64(); x = x % 10;`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `rand()` is a specification. There are some bad implementations out there, or perhaps all of them are bad, but I am not talking about implementations.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Uniform distribution and cryptographically secure are different properties. Uniform distribution may be desired simply to avoid skewing results of a study even when no concern about cryptographic security is present.

Comment: technically yes, because all the operations are actually bitwise under the hood. But realistically not because it can be much slower than other methods like multiplication by the multiplicative inverse. See [fast division/mod by 10^x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033210/995714)

Comment: Just a nostalgic note: x86 processors still support instructions for BDC arithmetics, like DAA. It had helped me in some limited case (e.g. small numbers) by some bitmasking trick, at the old age of MSDOS. But it does not scale well, and anyway on x64 it is no longer supported. As far as I know, there is nothing similar on different architectures.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini As I recall, it was not uncommon to have BCD support in the old days (1980's). I think both the Z80 and 6502 had support for BCD arithmetics.

Comment: @nielsen Correct. I should have written "there is nothing similar on modern architectures" :-)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the numbers being hexadecimal, that is just a _representation_ of the binary integer.  It has everything to do with being modulo of a power of two (16).  You cannot do the same with a power of 10 because it is binary not decimal.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini _"As far as I know, there is nothing similar on different architectures."_ : 6502, 6809, Z80 - all the good ones ;-)

Comment: @SimonGoater "_mod10() you linked to doesn't work correctly_" Not the first instance of code having a "typesetting bug" introduced. The published algorithm works after correcting the operations to find mod10 (two operations missing) by examining the contributory "mod15" section of that document. _"It is better to light a single candle than curse the darkness."_

Comment: Note that if you only need to do some almost-uniform (as uniform as possible) range reduction (ie if you don't care about the specifics of which number is reduced to which), you can use [a multiplication](https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/) (of which you use the high part of the result). It's not bitwise, but it is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to make `x%10` with bitwise operators in C?

No, not reasonably.

It's well known that if `N` is a power of 2, `x%N` can be efficiently computed by using a bitmask.  (For example, `x%16` is `x & 0x0F`, at least as long as `x` is unsigned.)  And in fact, this is so well known that virtually any C compiler knows how to do it, too.

Given the appealing efficiency and economy of power-of-2 moduli, it's tempting to look for similar tricks for other divisors.  Unfortunately, the math doesn't work out.  As this question's other answers show, while you can technically compute `x%10` using elaborate combinations of bitwise operators, it's not at all clear that there's any value to the exercise.
See also [Fast division/mod by 10<sup>x</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033210/fast-division-mod-by-10%cb%a3).

At the end of the day, if you want to compute `x%10`, the best way to express it in C is as the wholly unmagical but blatantly obvious:

```
x % 10
```

If there's a better way to implement it than actual division, leave it to the compiler to make the optimization for you.  And the code remains obvious, because everyone knows what `x % 10` means.

(And, indeed, even though I just said I didn't think there was a reasonable "bitwise shortcut" for computing `x % 10`, it turns out that gcc, at least, does tend to compile that particular expression down to a cryptic and presumably more-efficient sequence of multiplications, additions, and shifts, without any DIV instructions at all.)

If computing `x%10` is proving to be a bottleneck in your program, it's appropriate to ask, why are you computing `x%10` so much, and is there a better alternative?

You mentioned that you had "something like `rand() % 10`", as if you're generating individual, random, decimal digits.  If that's fundamentally what you need to do, there may not be a better way.  You're wasting a lot of the entropy that `rand()` is trying to give you, though.  You might want to consider a special-purpose random number generator.  Or if you're assembling your individual random digits into larger numbers, you might want to consider generating those larger numbers more directly.

Another place where `x%10` comes up a lot, of course, is when converting a number to its decimal representation.  For example, I once wrote an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library, and it works internally in binary, and when it has to convert one of its bignums into decimal to print it out, it can take a noticeable amount of time.  Adjusting the library to use a *decimal* representation internally lets it print things in decimal much more efficiently.  (Of course, it makes certain other operations significantly less efficient.)

If you're converting numbers to decimal as part of a serialization format, and if there's no requirement for the serialization format to be easily humanly readable, you might consider serializing integers in hexadecimal rather than decimal, because in that case the conversion will involve a bunch of computations of `x%16` instead of `x%10`.

Answer (score 1):

10 and 2 have a factor of 2 in common, so other than the first bit, every bit has an even value mod 10. Let’s divide everything by 2 and try to write a bitwise function that calculates an integer mod 5. Start at 1 and double mod 5: 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, …. The order of 2 in *U*<sub>5</sub> is 4.

That means that shifting an integer by a multiple of 4 bits, as long as it doesn’t shift off any bits, doesn’t change its value mod 5, and so you can fold it in on itself, e.g. for a 32-bit input:

```
n = (n >> 16) + (n & 0xffff);  // 0xffff + 0xffff <= 0x1fffe
n = (n >>  8) + (n &   0xff);  //  0x1ff +   0xff <=   0x2fe
n = (n >>  4) + (n &    0xf);  //   0x2f +    0xf <=    0x3e
n = (n >>  4) + (n &    0xf);  //    0x3 +    0xe <=    0x11
```

(shown after each operation: loose upper bounds, tight for the last)

Now we could branch to get from 0..17 (0x11) down to 0..9 down to 0..4:

```
if (n >= 10) n -= 10;
if (n >= 5) n -= 5;
return n;
```

Or use a 54-bit lookup table:

```
return (0x1111a223444688ULL >> (3 * n)) & 7;
```

Or a hybrid of those or something to stay inside 32 bits:

```
return n - 5 * (((0x7f800 >> n) & 2) + ((0x383e0 >> n) & 1));
return (0x4a528 >> n) & 4 | (0x4e738 >> n) & 2 | (0x4210 >> n) & 1;
```

Finally, `mod10` in terms of `mod5` is:

```
return (mod5(n >> 1) << 1) | (n & 1);
```

```js
const mod5 = n => {
  n = (n >>> 16) + (n & 0xffff);
  n = (n >>>  8) + (n &   0xff);
  n = (n >>>  4) + (n &    0xf);
  n = (n >>>  4) + (n &    0xf);
  return (
      (0x10840 >> n) & 4
    | (0x46318 >> n) & 2
    | (0x1294a >> n) & 1
  );
};

const mod10 = n =>
  (mod5(n >>> 1) << 1) | (n & 1);

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const g = canvas.getContext('2d');

const side = 16;
const cols = canvas.width / side;
const segments = Array.from({length: cols * canvas.height / side}, (_, i) => i);
const segmentSize = 2**32 / segments.length;

for (let i = segments.length; i > 1; i--) {
  const j = Math.random() * i >>> 0;
  [segments[j], segments[i - 1]] = [segments[i - 1], segments[j]];
}

const checkSegment = () => {
  if (segments.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  const segmentIndex = segments.pop();
  const low = segmentIndex * segmentSize;
  let good = true;
  
  let ref = low % 10;
  for (let i = low; i < low + segmentSize; i++, ref++) {
    if (ref === 10) ref = 0;
    if (mod10(i) !== ref) {
      good = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  g.fillStyle = good ? '#0f0' : 'red';
  
  const x = segmentIndex % cols;
  const y = segmentIndex / cols >>> 0;
  g.fillRect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(checkSegment);
};

canvas.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
canvas.width *= devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height *= devicePixelRatio;
g.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

checkSegment();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing analysis! but `+` is not a bitwise operation...

Comment: @chqrlie maybe not theoretically, even though if shifting is counted as a bitwise operation `+` can be decomposed into bitwise operations. Still, for today's processors there [is no practical difference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75811/why-is-addition-as-fast-as-bit-wise-operations-in-modern-processors#:~:text=Yes%3A%20integer%20addition%20is%20a,the%20others%2C%20but%20still), since addition is as fast as bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

Does this count? No loops, no conditionals, just `&`, `>>`, and array indexing. For 64-bit support, make the function twice as long.

```
int mod10(unsigned int n) {
    const int tab[2][10] = {
        { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 },
        { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 },
    };
    
    return tab[n & 1][
      tab[(n >> 1) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 2) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 3) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 4) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 5) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 6) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 7) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 8) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 9) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 10) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 11) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 12) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 13) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 14) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 15) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 16) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 17) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 18) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 19) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 20) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 21) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 22) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 23) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 24) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 25) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 26) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 27) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 28) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 29) & 1][
      tab[(n >> 30) & 1][
      (n >> 31) & 1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]];
}
```

Please note there is absolutely no reason to ever *use* this code, but it does work, and it may be worthwhile to *understand* it.

The working principle is that `tab[a][b]` equals `(2*b + a) % 10`. Another way to look at it is that we're taking 32 steps through a DFA, starting at state `0`, and each state has two arrows: arrow `0` leads to `(2*n)%10`, and arrow `1` leads to `(2*n+1)%10`. The final state is the result.

Comment: Does this handle signedness? It might be worth adding a comment about this.

Comment: Although this is a good exercise to understand it, unfortunately it wouldn't work in my code. I have an operation like `rand() % 10` and I would like to know if it's able to get the same result using bitwise operations with 1 or few lines of code. Sorry I wasn't clear in my OP.

Comment: @LoverofStructure good call. It didn't. I wiggled out of it by changing the input to be unsigned :)

Comment: I just edited my original post to make it clearer what I stated above in my comment.

Comment: @thevoyager no, a "nice" bitwise expression is impossible.

Comment: Now that OP clarified that the input comes from `rand()`, it is safe to assume that the input is non-negative :-)

Comment: Note that this breaks for values `>0xFFFFFFFFU` (i.e. that use more than 32 bit).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I think the answerer is aware of this; see the last sentence before the code.

Comment: @LoverofStructure He could use a type that wouldn't ever be larger than 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this which works, but there is probably a more elegant way to do it. Using a look-up table seems a bit like cheating, but I don't know how to get rid of the last few multiples of 10 without branching and looping etc. Anyway, it might be of interest to someone.

A 64 bit version could be constructed similarly but instead I've opted to play safe and have 64bit function which calls the 32 bit function for which all input values have been checked.

```
uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
/*
n = sum_{i=0 to 7} (2^4i)n_i
n % 10 = (n_0 + 6(sum_{i=1 to 7} n_i)) % 10

n = sum_{i=0 to 9} (2^i)b_i
n % 10 = (b_0 + 2(b_1 + b_5 + b_9) + 4(b_2 + b_6) + 8(b_3 + b_7) + 6(b_4 + b_8)) 
*/
  uint8_t lut[44] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    0, 1, 2, 3};
  uint32_t m = ((n >> 4) & 0xf) + ((n >> 8) & 0xf) + ((n >> 12) & 0xf) + ((n >> 16) & 0xf)
    + ((n >> 20) & 0xf) + ((n >> 24) & 0xf) + ((n >> 28) & 0xf); // max 7*15 = 105
  n = (n & 0xf) + (m << 2) + (m << 1); // max 15 + 630 = 645
  m = ((n & 0x10) >> 3) + ((n & 0x100) >> 7);
  n = (n & 0xf) + ((n & 0xe0) >> 4) + (m << 1) + m
    + ((n & 0x200) >> 8); // max 15 + 14 + 12 + 2 = 43
  return lut[n];
}


uint32_t uint64mod10(uint64_t n) {
  /*
n = n_0 + n_1*2^24 + n_2*2^48
n % 10 = (n_0 + 6(n_1 + n_2)) % 10 
  */
  uint64_t m = (n >> 48) + ((n >> 24) & 0xffffff);
  return uint32mod10((uint32_t)((n & 0xffffff) + (m << 2) + (m << 1)));
}
```

EDIT:

Something probably easy to code on a microcontroller which could actually be extended for use for binary to decimal conversion for 32bit unsigned integers is as follows.

```
static inline uint32_t uint32divby5(uint32_t n) {  
  uint32_t a, m = (n >> 2) - (n >> 4);
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  m = (n - m) >> 2;
  a = m + (m << 2);
  if (a > n) return m - 1;
  return m;
}

uint32_t uint32mod10b(uint32_t n) {
  uint32_t m = uint32divby5(n >> 1);
  return n - (m << 3) - (m << 1);
}
```

EDIT2:

Another alternative if 64bit arithmetic is available,

```
static inline uint32_t fastdiv16(uint16_t denom, uint32_t lp30, uint64_t m, uint32_t num)  {
  //result = num/denom
  //uint64_t m = (((uint64_t)1 << 63) / denom);
  //uint32_t lp30 = 30 + lzcnt(m);
  //m = m >> (63 - lp30);
  uint64_t q = (num  * m) >> lp30;
  uint64_t test = q*denom;
  return (uint32_t)(q + 1 - (test + denom > num));
}


uint32_t uint32mod10c(uint32_t n) {
  uint32_t m = fastdiv16(10, 34, 1717986918, n);
  return n - (m << 3) - (m << 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a number in the range of 0-99 you can use:

```
x - (10*((x*103)>>10)
```

It's not strictly bit operations, and it's questionable if it would be faster than a remainder operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a kind of "digit sum", whereas the first 4 bits map to 1, 2, 4, 8 and the following bits to the repeating sequence 6, 2, 4, 8. If the resulting sum is bigger than 15 you can repeat this process till you finally get a sum between 0 and 15 (inclusive), after which you only need to subtract 10 once if it's bigger than 9.

Implementation wise, it's useful to note that these numbers match the place values of the first 4 bits except for every 4th bit (exclusive the 0th bit that is) where we have to adjust it by adding a 5. So we can treat this as a sum of nibbles, with an additional 5 for every uneven nibble except the lowest. (Or if you prefer: as a sum of hex digest with an additional 5 for every uneven digit except for the least significant digit).

This can be nicely parallelized by first adding neighboring nibbles, then neighboring octets etc. I constructed this example for a 32-bit number:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
     uint32_t odd = (n & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4;
     uint32_t even = n & 0x0f0f0f0f;
     uint32_t fives = (odd & 0x01010101) + (even & 0x01010100);

     // Max expected sum of two nibbles is 40
     uint32_t sum = odd + even + fives * 5;
     odd = (sum & 0xff00ff00) >> 8; // Mask 0x3f003f00 would also work
     even = sum & 0x00ff00ff;

     // Max expected sum of two octets is 80
     sum = odd + even;
     odd = (sum & 0xffff0000) >> 16; // Mask 0x007f0000 would also work
     even = sum & 0x0000ffff;

     // Max exected sum at this point is 155
     sum = odd + even; 
     odd = (sum & 0xf0) >> 4;
     even = sum & 0x0f;
     sum = odd + even + (odd & 1) * 5;

     // Max expected sum at this point is 27
     if (sum > 19) sum -= 20;
     else if (sum > 9) sum -= 10;
     return sum;
}
```

As noted in the comments, the highest sum we expect after the first iteration is 155, so it's not really necessary to do another full iteration and handling the last two nibbles is enough. After that, we may get 27, but instead of adding nibbles again, I decided to just conditionally subtract 20.

Note that the multiplication by 5 can be easily replaced with a bit-operation (i.e. `i * 5 == i + (i << 2)`) but this is something the compiler will probably do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While reading about the [Double Dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) algorithm, I got another idea to solve this: We could basically do the same thing but only do the checks for the "last" (least significant) digit, since that's what we're interested in:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
     uint64_t scratch = n;
     scratch <<= 3;
     for (int i=0; i<29; i++) {
          if ((scratch & 0xf00000000) > 0x400000000) {
               scratch += 0x300000000;
          }
          scratch <<= 1;
     }
     return (scratch >> 32) & 0xf;
}
```

The main advantage could be that it's simple. In my tests, this is quite a bit slower than my other proposal. Though, unrolling the loop may help.

Also note that if you want to follow this implementation, you need to be able to shift an integer type bigger than your input type. Otherwise, you could use a separate variable and explicitly handle the carry during shifting. Although this will make the code more complicated again.

---

Addendum

On second thought, it's not really necessary to use a `scratch` variable. Since we're only interested in the last digit, we can do everything we need within the input variable:

```
uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
     if ((n & 0xe0000000) > 0x80000000) {
          n += 0x60000000;
     }
     for (int i=0; i<28; i++) {
          if ((n & 0xf0000000) > 0x40000000) {
               n += 0x30000000;
          }
          n <<= 1;
     }
     return n >> 28;
}
```

But then I realize that adding a 3 before doubling is equivalent to subtracting its complement `16 - 3*2 = 10`, so we could use this much simpler solution of subtracting power of 2 multiples of 10:

```
uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
     for (uint32_t sub = 0xa0000000; n > 9; sub >>= 1) {
          if (n >= sub) {
               n -= sub;
          }
     }
     return n;
}
```

That also has the advantage that it may need much fewer iterations. In fact, that's the solution I came up with before I came up with the solution in my other answer. But now it becomes hard to argue that this is a "bitwise operator" solution... On the other hand, since we only have to handle a few cases, we could replace the subtraction with bitwise operations:

```
uint32_t uint32mod10(uint32_t n) {
     int i;
     for (i=0; i<28 && n>9; i++) {
          switch (n & 0xf0000000) {
          case 0x80000000:
               n <<= 2;
               i++;
               n |= 0xc0000000;
               break;
          case 0x90000000:
               n <<= 1;
               n ^= 0xa0000000;
               break;
          case 0xa0000000:
          case 0xb0000000:
               n <<= 3;
               i += 2;
               break;
          case 0xc0000000:
          case 0xd0000000:
               n <<= 2;
               i++;
               n |= 0x80000000;
               break;
          case 0xe0000000:
          case 0xf0000000:
               n <<= 1;
               n ^= 0x40000000;
               break;
          default:
               n <<=1;
          }
     }
     return n >> i;
}
```

Now that may take even fewer iterations since we can skip some bits depending on the case (and you could also add cases like `0` to skip 4 bits at once). But incrementing a counter and even greater/less-than comparisons can be seen as "non-bitwise" so you'd need to unroll this loop completely and add further ending conditions if you want to avoid that.

Comment: This would be more portable if you didn't rely on `union` type punning with bit-fields, but rather accessed the least significant digit using bit masks like `& 0xf`. Your code currently relies on Little Endian memory layout and a specific layout for the bit-field.

Comment: @JanSchultke I wanted to avoid having to handle the carry explicitly. But you're right, I can do everything I need directly on the `scratch` variable, and the `union` just complicates things. The bitfield also probably has to be translated to `&` operations by the compiler, so runtime wise it shouldn't make much of a difference. So I adapted my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out the issue!

Comment: Here is also an interesting suggestion: https://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod10 (for mod 10 and a few others). It also needs a few conditional subtractions, though.

Comment: @DavidOngaro The cited link has correct code for "mod 15", but when that code was _almost_ replicated in its "mod 10" section, its logic was truncated. The paper's "mod 10" version is wrong for large value integers... The (trivial) correction is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: @Fe203 You're right, and the first value it fails for is 510 -- not even that large. I suppose adding a line `if (a > 29) a = a - 25;` should fix it.

Comment: @DavidOngaro Correctly adapting the paper's "mod 15" section, without calling it as a subordinate function, I found having *three* instances of `if (a > 14) a = a - 15;` in a row worked nicely. Not elegant, but functional and seems to return correct values for the test cases I explored... Cheers!

Comment: @Fe203 Ok, but shouldn't be having just one additional condition be better? That is, unless the compiler or the CPU pipeline finds an optimization due to 3 equal statements in a row.

Comment: @DavidOngaro While fewer operations are, of course, better, checking the "mod 15" algorithm presented in the paper (as a callable function), shows 3 different `return` statements gated by two `if()` conditionals. A person could write a short `if/else if` chain, but it seems there's no escaping having multiple possible situations to deal with at the end of the "mod15()" code... A single `if()` won't be sufficient...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, since adding a single `if (a > 29) a = a - 25;` condition before the `if (a > 14) a = a - 15;` works. But it's true that if we want to keep the "mod 5" code unmodified (e.g. to call it as a function or as a macro) then your proposal of adding two more `if (a > 14) a = a - 15;` afterward may be the only viable way.